# Is there a way to select options page and press submit to transfer the info into the selected option page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a form with textboxes and options with choices of pages based on job’s types. I want that when the end user entering the information into the textbox selects the option of the page then press the submit the info transfers and shows it in the selected page.

```html
<div>
  <H1>SELECT A page:</H1>
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="">
    <select id="ddl" name="dd1" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="IT">IT.php</option>
      <option value="Health">Health.php</option>
      <option value="HR">HR.php</option>
      <option value="Education">Education.php</option>
      <option value="Art">Art.php</option>
    </select>

    <select id="ddl2" name="dd12">
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <!--<input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size:20px; " />-->

    <!--in this submit I want the code that makes the info transfer into selected page-->
    <button id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      var linkTo = $('select[name="dd1"]').val();
      var goTo;

      switch (linkTo) {
        case 'IT':
          goTo = "IT.php";
          break;
        case 'Health':
          goTo = "Health.php";
          break;
      }

      case 'HR':
        goTo = "HR.php";
        break;
      case 'Education':
        goTo = "Education.php";
        break;
    }

    case 'Art':
      goTo = "Art.php";
      break;
  }

  $("#myForm").attr("action", goTo);
  $("#myform").submit();
});
});
```

Comment: I've formatted your code to make it easier to read. You can see from this that your `switch` logic is not correctly structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already getting the link from select option. I think no need to use switch .

You can try.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  var linkTo = $('select[name="dd1"]').val();
  $("#myForm").attr("action", linkTo+'.php');
  $("#myform").submit();
});
});
</script>
```

Form.

```
<div>
  <H1>SELECT A page:</H1>

  <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="">
 <!-- For example you have text field with name attr textbox -->
  <input type="text" name="textbox">
    <select id="ddl" name="dd1">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="check">IT.php</option>
      <option value="Health">Health.php</option>
      <option value="HR">HR.php</option>
      <option value="Education">Education.php</option>
      <option value="Art">Art.php</option>
    </select>

    <select id="ddl2" name="dd12">
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <!--<input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size:20px; " />-->

    <!--in this submit I want the code that makes the info transfer into selected page-->
    <button id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Form is using get method. When you submit the form all the form data will go to selected page with a query string in URL like.

```
example.com/IT.php?textbox=test&dd1=IT
```

So on selected page you can get the value using $_GET.

```
 <?php
    $dd1 = $_GET['dd1'];
    $ddl2 = $_GET['ddl2'];
    echo $textbox = $_GET['textbox'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank u for your help. And I want to ask you how I can make what I wrote in textbox shows on the selected page @Shivendra Singh

Comment: Let's you have text field -  <input type="text" name="textbox"> in form. So on selected page you can get textbox value by $_GET['textbox'];

Comment: I Do the same thing based on your edit but the result on my URL shows like this (http://localhost/IT.php?dd1=IT&submit=) without the info inside the textbox

Comment: did you add '<input type="text" name="textbox">' in your form?

Comment: Glad to help :)